# Source qualifier allowing value more than defined size in Informatica

Tags: workflow, scale, precision, informatica, sqldatatypes

One of my informatica session behaving weird. For a particular column precision and scale values are defined as 17,16respectively and enable the high precision is on.
As per the precision and scale values it should allow the numbers which are having only single digit before the decimal point but in my session it allowing upto 2digits before the decimal point and failing for 3digits before the decimal point with the error **Invalid number**
. I am confused why it's allowing 2digits numbers as it should fail for them too?
Ex: precision 17,scale 16
1.4567--allowed
12.4567--allowed
123.4567-- rejected

In addition to it I observed that in the source that column has  data type as number but coming to source qualifier same column has data type decimal. Why this internal convertion happened?

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

As for the second part of the question: one of `Source Qualifier` transformation fuctions is to convert any Source data types to PowerCenter data types. Whatever source you will use, `Source Qualifier` will convert the data types. This way you end up with same data types and comparison between Orace and MS SQL Server won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is whats happening in case of '12.4567 -- allowed'. Since you have high precision mode on, infa is converting decimal to double automatically. Double is 8byte data. So, if you set something
col(11,9) and trying to insert 1234567890.1, infa will fail.
Summary -
*If you specify the precision greater than the maximum number of digits, the Data Integration Service converts decimal values to double in high precision mode.*

This is as per Infa documentation

```
8 bytes (if high precision is off or precision is greater than 38) 
16 bytes (if precision <= 18 and high precision is on) 
20 bytes (if precision > 18 and <= 28) 
24 bytes (if precision > 28 and <= 38)
```

Decimal value with declared precision and scale. Scale must be less than or equal to precision.
For transformations that support precision up to 38 digits, the precision is 1 to 38 digits, and the scale is 0 to 38.
For transformations that support precision up to 28 digits, the precision is 1 to 28 digits, and the scale is 0 to 28.
If you specify the precision greater than the maximum number of digits, the Data Integration Service converts decimal values to double in high precision mode.

https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-2/developer-tool-guide/data-type-reference/transformation-data-types.html